# Keep on querying the time till it matches a given time

Tags: android, timer, alarm, hour

I want to build an application with a concept that I have to perform an action at a given time which is prespecified. That is it is basically like an alarm.

For that , I want to constantly query the timing so that whenever I find that the present HOUR_OF_DAY and MINUTE matches the input, I perform the given action

In Windows phone, there is the concept if a ticker which I used. How to do it in android? It would be great if I could get the code for it.

Comment: You already got your solution.Set an alarm for the input time.It will trigger that time so you can perform the action.There is nothing necessary like constantly querying.

Comment: How do I make use of the triggered timing? How does it happen? Can you give me an example for say 9:30 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Complete example to use [AlarmManager](http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/setting-up-alarm-using-alarmmanager-and-waking-up-screen-and-unlocking-keypad-on-alarm-goes-off-in-android/) in Android.

Follow this tutorial, read,understand and implement.

---

You should not go with a thought to create a self program or service to check the timings each second else it will eat up all the battery the best solution is to use AlarmManager.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html). It allows you to schedule your application to run at given times